# Why am I getting this warning about utility classes in Java

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and OOPS and while programming a basic Hello World in eclipse, I see a yellow triangle telling me **'utility classes should not have a public or default constructor'**. I'm not able to understand why exactly is this happening and what does it mean? What am I doing not right?

```
class HelloWorld {


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Hola Mundo!");

}


  }
```

EDIT1: Edited the code to include changes suggested.

```
final class HelloWorld {


private HelloWorld()
{
    throw new AssertionError("Instantiating utility class...");

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Hola Mundo!");

}


}
```

Still getting the alert on the line Class HelloWorld.

Edit2:

Created a new class and now it works. Thanks Jon.Why does the old class still give warning? Bohemian I'm still not aware about the concepts mentioned by you in your post.  I would come back to them once I get a better idea. Thank you for explaining things.

Comment: Why does it matter if users instantiate a utility class? They will soon find out there is nothing to it and delete the instantiation code. On the other hand, a private constructor will be dead code. Either it will bring your test coverage down or force you into writing a test (that uses ugly reflection hacks) that tests, well, dead code.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It means that someone can write:

```
HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
```

when you *probably* don't want them to - you're not providing any instance members, so why allow them to create instances? Rewrite your code as:

```
final class HelloWorld {

    private HelloWorld() {
        // Prevent instantiation
        // Optional: throw an exception e.g. AssertionError
        // if this ever *is* called
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hola Mundo!");
    }
}
```

Comment: and should `throw new AssertionError("Instantiating utility class...")` in the constructor to prevent accidental instantiation within Utility(`HelloWorld`) class

Comment: @Jon I know you're a precise person, so you should know your comment `throw an exception e.g. AssertionError` has a flaw... `AssertionError` is not an `Exception` (it's an `Error`)

Comment: I made the code changes and included the Assertion Error also but still it's giving the same warning. Now is this a bug in eclipse?

Comment: @Bohemian: It's an exception, but not an Exception. There's a difference. For example, from the JLS: "The unchecked exceptions classes are the class RuntimeException and its subclasses, and the class Error and its subclasses."

Comment: @gizgok: You're sure you made the constructor private? Have you tried the *exact* code I provided here, e.g. as a new class?

Comment: Created a new class and it worked. Why does the old class still give warning?

Comment: @gizgok - you might need to clean your project to force it to recompile? (Project->Clean in eclipse)

Comment: @Jon - OK, you got me with the JLS spec :)

Comment: @Matt Did that and still gives the warning.

Comment: @gizgok: It sounds like your Eclipse may be slightly hosed - or you haven't *really* changed it as you think you have. Try changing your existing code to include a bona fide *error*. Or perhaps this warning comes from some sort of external build tool you're running?

Comment: @Jon Most likely an external build tool.

Comment: I hate this Checkstyle warning, it adds no value.  If an instantation is made of this utility class, the instantiator is at fault -- flag that, don't flag a perfectly reasonable Utility class and force me to add an ugly dummy constructor

Comment: @john16384: I strongly disagree. You should make your API as easy as possible to use correctly, and as hard as possible to use incorrectly. If an operation makes no sense, prohibit it. Of course, it would be better if there were language support for this, like static classes in C#.

Comment: This is another ridiculous PMD rule. Plus the solution will yield worse coverage since the private constructor is never invoked.

Answer (score 25):

What Jon said, but you should know too that every class has a constructor, whether you declare one or not. If you do not declare one, then the "default constructor" is implicitly defined for you.

In other words, these two classes are identical in behaviour:

```
public class ClassA {
}


public class ClassB {
    public ClassB() {
    }
}
```

### BEWARE: Having a private constructor does not prevent instantiation!

And just to be anal, having a private constructor **does not** prevent someone from instantiating your class, it just makes it harder:

There are (at least) two ways to get around it:

Declare a factory method (obvious, but if it's your company's code, someone can do this):

```
public class ClassA {
    private ClassA() {}

    public static ClassA create() {
        return new ClassA(); // oops! this one got away
    }
}
```

Use reflection (sneaky, and seems wrong somehow, but it works!):

```
public class ClassA {
    private ClassA() {}
}

// Elsewhere, in another class across town:
Constructor<?> constructor = ClassA.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
// constructor private? no problem... just make it not private!
constructor.setAccessible(true); // muhahahaha
Object obj = constructor.newInstance();
System.out.println(obj.getClass().getSimpleName());  // Prints ClassA!
```

The only way to guarantee no one creates an instance is to throw an exception in a (might as well make it private) constructor:

```
public class ClassA {
    private ClassA() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For completeness, none of the responders have so far commented on the other issue with your original class

```
class HelloWorld {
```

which, as suggested, you turned into

```
final class HelloWorld {
```

The `final` keyword on a Java class prohibits other classes from extending (inheriting from) it. If you don't make a class final, an extending class can make use of all sorts of things you might not have intended, because the extending class has access to the `protected` members of the inherited class.

It is good practice to always make your classes either `abstract` or `final`, meaning they are intended **only** for, or **not** for, inheriting. There will be plenty of times when you will design a class to be both instantiable (not abstract) and extendable (not final), but making this a conscious decision is a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to write a utility class is you have an enum with no instances. You can do with with Java 5.0 and above.

```
public enum Utility {;
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Hola Mundo!");
    }
}
```

You don't have to define a private constructor and you cannot create instances using inner classes or other tricks like reflection. (If you ignore the Unsafe class ;)

BTW: Some see using an `enum` as a hack, but for me it explicitly says "I have a class with no instances" rather than preventing instances being created which is indirect.

Comment: The simplest and probably the best.

Comment: Notice the semicolon hidden there behind the opening curly brace of this enum? That is needed to indicate an empty enum. I think that's a bit tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#HideUtilityClassConstructor
I'm assuming you are using CheckStyle.

Comment: A newbie using CheckStyle is highly unlikely scenario but your link is sufficient

Comment: @anergy, I'm using Checkstyle right now, and I also see a yellow triangle showing me the same message when I hover over it.  I don't think I've ever noticed this warning appearing in Eclipse or RSA alone.  In any case, geff_chang's link helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring application, try this:

Create a configuration file that suppress checks on files, `checkstyle-suppressions.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
        "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_0.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress files="SpringBootApplication.java" checks="HideUtilityClassConstructor" />
</suppressions>
```

In `maven-checkstyle-plugin` plugin configuration, add location of `checkstyle-suppressions.xml`

```
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>quality/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        <suppressionsLocation>quality/checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
```