# Java Hello World to pass CheckStyle

Tags: java, checkstyle

So I'm new to using checkstyle and for my simple HelloWorld java program, I'm receiving a lot of errors I don't understand.

My code:

```
package <package_name>;

/**
* A simple class to compile.
*/
public class HelloWorld {

 /**
  * @param args standard main parameters
  */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the errors:

```
Line 6: Utility classes should not have a public or default constructor
Line 10: Parameter args should be final
```

Why is this occurring? Is it necessary for me to create a private constructor for my `main` class and make the default arguments final?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Utility classes like your Main class, it is better to create a private constructor in order to don't let java compiler write itself the default no args constructor `Main()`.

Java always makes a copy of parameters before sending them to methods. The final keyword here only means that inside the method the variables can not be reassigned. (note that if you have a final object like in your case `String[]`, you can still change the attributes of the object).

Answer (score 2):

1st issue is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766277/why-am-i-getting-this-warning-about-utility-classes-in-java) and is documented [here](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#HideUtilityClassConstructor). Short answer is that you're not providing any instance members to `HelloWorld` class, so why allow them to create instances? That's why it's recommended to create a `private` constructor.

2nd issue - is stated [here](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#FinalParameters). Short answer - Changing the value of parameters during the execution of the method's algorithm can be confusing and should be avoided. That's why it's recommended to declare them `final`

Answer (score 1):

You **may** need to create at least a private constructor, add this:

```
/**
 * Private default constructor
 */
private HelloWorld () {
}
```

That should make it away. The reason here is because the Java compiler "thinks" you want to make a utilities class because it sees only public static methods. In that case it is best practice, to have a private default constructor.

For this "Hello World" example it is fine to do so. But in RL code, you want to create an instance from your `HelloWorld` class and then add a "business" method (a method containing your logic) to it.

**Edit:** The warning in line 10 is a good one, as using `final` for parameters in general means that you cannot change the parameter's value:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo () {
    }

    public void doBar (final Bar bar) {
        // Won't work:
        bar = null;

        // Will work!
        bar.callMe();
    }
}

public class Bar {
    public Bar {
    }

    public void callMe () {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Now just remove that `final` and it will compile but throw a warning at you that you change a parameter. This causes unexpected side effects, that (later in larger projects) a method has changed some parameter "somewhere".

Just try to imagine: +200k lines of code (no comments!) and no `final` for parameters ... A perfect chaos ...

The accepted answer's poster said it, just more details here and a good reason.